# how to get if conditon to work with null variable from database

Tags: php, mysql

Before, I insert data to database using normal sql code and I use ("") to insert the empty var into database.

Now I use pdo and I use (NULL) to insert the empty value to database.

I know that ("") and (NULL) is different. But I get problem to script the variable that´s NULL....well maybe I´m not good at explaining. let´s see my script:

```
$problem=$rs['problem']; ///Here comes with the NULL from database.

    if (is_null($problem)) {
        echo"this is null";
    } else {
        echo"this is not null";
    } 

OR
    if (empty($problem) ) {
        echo "this is null";
    } else {
        echo "this is not null";
    } 

OR 
    if (isset($problem)==NULL) {            
        echo "this is null";
    } else {
        echo "this is not null ";           
    }
```

Whether there´re empty or have data in the table, the result I get from these 3 script is only "this is null"

I have no idea how I can get this correct.

Comment: Missing quotes here: `$problem=$rs['problem'];`

Comment: `var_dump($problem);`

Comment: you mean I have to change from  $problem=$rs['problem'];  to var_dump($problem);?

Comment: No! a) `$problem=$rs[problem]` lacks the quotes, this gives a warning, but nothing serious. b) dump the contents of $problem to see what you have!

Comment: @arkascha That's probably why it isn't an answer.  I would consider it serious because it'll look for a constant called `problem`, and if some day there is one, it'll use that instead of the actual string `'problem'`.  Also, others have already stated before you to dump `$problem`.

Comment: @BLaZuRE Both your statements are true, but... I just tried to help the OP understand what was asked of him. His comment suggested he did _not_ understand the comments... Sorry that I tried to help.

Comment: What is that mean to express: `if (isset($problem)==NULL)`? What is the `==NULL` doing in there? `isset()` returns a boolean!

Comment: I have test with var_dump($problem);
And the result I got is NULL  While the script I use says : this is not null no matter what it´s null or not.

Comment: Show how you get null in that variable,post more code.

Comment: I use the same code...but just test by change the query to differences colume with NULL and not NULL but all I get from var_dump($problem); Is only null all the time..

Comment: Can you update your question and show us what comes before `$problem=$rs['problem'];`? Maybe there's something missing in your previous steps that may help us debug your code.

Comment: @Sutandiono It seems to have been `NULL`.  The OP seems to be under the assumption that changing to PDO was the solution, without making anything clear, according to the comments in the answers.

Comment: @BLaZuRE Yup. The OP mentioned "Whether there´re empty or have data in the table, the result I get from these 3 script is only "this is null"". That's why I suspect there's something which changed her/his `$rs['problem'] to NULL from where s/he receives the result to the conditional statements.

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean to say that the empty value can either be NULL or '' (empty string)?

Try this:

```
if (is_null ($problem) || empty ($problem))
{
   echo "This is null";
}
else
{
   echo "This is not null";
}
```

By the way, I'm not sure if it's a typo or not, but you're missing a white space after the echo. It should be `echo "This is null";`

Comment: I don´t think so...Because I also test with the script below, and it´s the same. I wonder if something wrong with the database.